# using Javascript and firebase in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm trying to use firebase in angular but don't know why my localhost cannot function with my javascript. 
It functions well if i put all the code in index.html but i just wondered why it cannot function in my contact.component.html when i using localhost.
looks like my javascript cannot function in html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAa0U.png)

```js
//here is my main.js
// Initialize Firebase (ADD YOUR OWN DATA)
var config = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "listing-ed9ac.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://listing-ed9ac.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "listing-ed9ac",
  storageBucket: "listing-ed9ac.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "122342013620"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Reference messages collection
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');

// Listen for form submit
document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

// Submit form
function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get values
  var name = getInputVal('name');
  var company = getInputVal('company');
  var email = getInputVal('email');
  var phone = getInputVal('phone');
  var message = getInputVal('message');

  // Save message
  saveMessage(name, company, email, phone, message);



  // Clear form
  document.getElementById('contactForm').reset();
}

// Function to get get form values
function getInputVal(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

// Save message to firebase
function saveMessage(name, company, email, phone, message) {
  var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();
  newMessageRef.set({
    name: name,
    company: company,
    email: email,
    phone: phone,
    message: message
  });
}
```

```html
//here is my contact.component.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>try</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="showcase">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>
        Contact Us
      </h1>
    </div>
  </section>

  <html>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="brand"><span>Car</span> Rental</h1>
      <div class="wrapper animated bounceInLeft">
        <div class="company-info">
          <h3>Car Rental</h3>
          <p>
            Get in touch with us via the Contact Form. Car Rental will be in touch with you shortly.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
          <h3>Email Us</h3>
          <div class="alert">Your message has been sent</div>
          <form id="contactForm">
            <p>
              <label>Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Company</label>
              <input type="text" name="company" id="company">
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Email Address</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Phone Number</label>
              <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
            </p>
            <p class="full">
              <label>Message</label>
              <textarea name="message" rows="5" id="message"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="full">
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>

  </html>

  <section id="showcase2">
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        HAWK RENT A CAR (M) SDN BHD
      </p>
      <p>
        No 4 Jalan SS13/3E,Subang Jaya Industrial Estate, 47500 Subang Jaya,Selangor Darul Ehsan
      </p>
      <p>
        Tel: 1300886488(Within Malaysia) / +603-56316488
      </p>
      <p>
        Fax : +603-56356466
      </p>
      <p>
        Email: reservations@hawkrentacar.com.my
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>


</body>

</html>
<footer>
  <p>Copyright &copy; 2017 Designed by ckyong </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Can you, please, provide the entire code in your .ts file of your component? I am particularly talking about the constructor of your class and the modules you imported.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vcpZWxRwF1paSqcDHP9M8H-uOXJp_f3Z

Comment: here is my source code and i wonder is that the problem on the contact.component.html which is my sub component.....coz i try to click the submit button and realised that it didn't alert when the form didn't fill in

Comment: One of the suggestions I can give to you very quickly is that you need to install and to  
`import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database'` in your project. Maybe a look to this repo might help you: https://github.com/coltaemanuela/Realtime-Chat-with-Angular4/blob/master/src/app/chat/chat.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

It old question but lot of newbies to Angular (2+) might face this.
The code snippets shared only work with pure JavaScript (vanilla JavaScript).
For Angular the different way, install angularfire2 module, and proceed. The syntax is different in the angularfire2 module.

If I am right the TypeScript using angularfire2 will be converted to equivalent JavaScript (similar to your code you shared)

Comment: Why is it impossible to find a Vanilla implementation of Firebase. Firebase SDKs are simply not that difficult to use, there is no need for a wrapper in my opinion...

Comment: Vanilla implementation of firebase is very, I agree. As Frameworks support component creation and reusability of component, I had to work with frameworks, But There is no clear documentation or guide to use firebase with frameworks like Angular or react. Self-learning newbies like me find it difficult to use firebase with frameworks.